# Affecting just one object of a collection instance in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I change an individual object of a collection instance after the *Instance on Points* node. For example, I'd like the spheres to be higher in that image. How can I use nodes such as *Translate Instances* but for just one of my collection objects. My instinct would be to assign the index in the selection but I can't figure out how.

[image: My instinct tells me to input something in selection but what?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This answer here only serves to complete the range of possibilities...

If the transformation for a certain object should always be the same, then it is recommended to perform it ideally **BEFORE** the instantiation.

This way, this operation does not have to be applied to a large number of objects, but happens only once, which can possibly achieve a gain in terms of performance:

[image]

PS: And by the way, the correct rotation for your instances is provided directly by the node `Distribute Points on Faces`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much! And how would you go about setting a material for one objetc, and another material for the rest?

Comment: @Enashka Ideally, with this setup, you should define the materials directly in the objects you instantiate here.

Answer (score 3):

your instinct is right, you can do it like this:

[image]

instead of geometry to instance, you would take your collection ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setup. For example if you have 3 objects as instances, you can test which of the indices is the object you want to translate.

[image]