# Random scaling of selected collection instance object gives strange results

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to randomize the Z scale of only the cubes in my collection.

It works fine for all objects, but as soon as I plug the equal node to the Scale Instance Selection, nothing happens to my squares, but one single pyramid is affected. Very strange.

I have been at it for 2 hours. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Affecting just one object of a collection instance in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273756/affecting-just-one-object-of-a-collection-instance-in-geometry-node)

Comment: That post (which was actually from me as well) doesn't answer that particular problem. Can anyone try reproducing what I'm describing here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see what you mean. Please forgive me! The answer will follow shortly (But please still look at the other question/answer and give us feedback on it, because I don't like open-ended questions, thanks!).

Comment: Hey Quellenform. Sorry, I am new to this site. I commented on your very helpful answer on that other question and which helped me greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you would have to capture the index of an instance so that you can compare this value with a value of your choice after instantiation.

Unfortunately, all the attributes that you would capture in the instances before instantiation are no longer available after instantiation.

Therefore, you would have to go the other way around, and capture the index in the points on which you instantiate your objects.

You then use this index in the node `Instance on Points` as *Instance Index*.

The great thing about this is: This value is available to you in this form even after instantiation, so you can easily create a selection afterwards and apply a random scaling to instances with a certain index:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: @Enashka PS: Also, please be kind enough not to leave any answers without a response. It would be great if you give feedback and let us know if a solution could be found, and if not, if you have any further questions about it. Thanks! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link. I didn't know I had to click on the check mark. I will do so from now on.. And thank you for the solution to my problem. You have helped me improve greatly.

Comment: @Enashka You are welcome! Thank you for helping to make this site great!

Comment: @quellenform: you watched D.Trump too often.... :D